# "No such file or directory, /src/app/templateCacheHtml.js" when running gulp build

Tags: angularjs, generator-gulp-angular

I'm using the gulp-angular yeoman generator and if I create a new project, and then run gulp build or gulp serve:dist I get back this error:

Whenever I try to build my project, I get this error:

> [16:03:56] gulp-inject 2 files into index.less. fs.js:887 return
>   binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path)); ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat
>   '/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/src/app/templateCacheHtml.js' at
>   Error (native) at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:887:18) at
>   DestroyableTransform.TransformStream as _transform at
>   DestroyableTransform.Transform.read
>   (/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:159:10)
>   at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write
>   (/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:147:83)
>   at doWrite
>   (/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:313:64)
>   at writeOrBuffer
>   (/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:302:5)
>   at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write
>   (/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:241:11)
>   at write
>   (/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/node_modules/gulp-concat/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
>   at flow
>   (/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/node_modules/gulp-concat/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
>   at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable
>   (/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/node_modules/gulp-concat/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:664:5)
>   at emitNone (events.js:80:13) at DestroyableTransform.emit
>   (events.js:179:7) at emitReadable
>   (/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/node_modules/gulp-concat/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:448:10)
>   at emitReadable
>   (/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/node_modules/gulp-concat/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:444:5)
>   at readableAddChunk
>   (/Users/danielrvt/IdeaProjects/rztest/node_modules/gulp-concat/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:187:9)

Comment: I just started receiving this error as well for an existing script. It's likely a new version of a plugin causing the issue, but I'm still investigating as to which it might be.

Comment: Ok, I found that if I create an empty 'templateCacheHtml.js' file under /src/app it seems to build. But, why is this happening now? Before it worked perfectly!

Comment: From a coworker, "We solved [another instance of this] by updating the version of  gulp-angular-templatecacheto ~2.0.0" in package.json.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Fix

The fix included in issue #37 has been released so the below workaround is no longer necessary. The error should not be present anymore after performing an `npm update`.

---

### Cause

This error is being caused by a recent update (v1.8.3) in the [`gulp-header`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header) library.

An [issue](https://github.com/tracker1/gulp-header/issues/37) has already been created for you to track.

`gulp-angular-templatecache` has an indirect dependency on `gulp-header`, which is mentioned in a few of the comments.

### Workaround

Until a fix is released, you can add a node dependency for the previous version of `gulp-header` to package.json. However, the ticket has been closed so a release should come shortly.

```
"dependencies": {
    "gulp-header": "1.8.2"
}
```

Comment: While this does indeed fix the issue, I would keep in mind that it is rather difficult to prevent such problems from reoccurring in the future because npm dependencies are commonly using non-strict versions (~ and ^). But committing node_modules to version control to keep the builds deterministic is just painful.

Comment: @OlliS Yeah, I'd much rather make these fixes with node dependencies on an as-needed basis rather than commit node_modules... Hate repository bloat.